# How to determine if variable was instantiated using new

Tags: javascript

How can I determine if Javascript variable was instantiated using `new`, i.e. is an object in OOP sense. Object literals `{a: 1}` or arrays `['a', 'b']` should not cause false positives.

*Based on comments, further explanation on use case:*

Serializing and transferring object data (using out-of-the-box normal JSON) causes them to appear as dumb object literals at the receiving end. Manual reviving needs to be done in order to get them fully rejuvenated as objects, so that they have methods and all things object-like. I'm researching if this rejuvenation can be done in an elegant way and as part of the solution I need to know if this original question can be answered.

Please don't get confused by this use case, it involves a whole lot of and even more things that are not in the scope of this question. Let's keep them elsewhere.

*Based on comments, further code example:*

(generated from Typescript)

```
var C = (function () {
    function C() {
        this.v = 1;
    }
    C.prototype.f = function () {
        console.log('v=' + this.v);
    };
    return C;
})();

var c = new C();

c.f();

var cSerializedCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(c));

cSerializedCopy.f();
```

will give the following output:

```
v=1

.../test.js:17
cSerializedCopy.f();
                ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'f'
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../test.js:17:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Obviously the two "objects" have something of a difference don't you think. Can this be determined in some simple and waterproof way?

Comment: But those are also objects?

Comment: `{a: 1}` IS an object. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: If you are asking `was this object made by a constructor` then you might look at the `prototype` property -- but even that can be faked.  Due to the extremely dynamic nature of JavaScript, nothing is reliable.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: After creation there is _no difference_ between `var o = new Object(); o.a = 1;` and `var o = {a: 1}`.

Comment: Actually OP happens to be right. Profiler tools can tell what "classes" things are - how?

Comment: @AlexWayne really? try doing a heap dump and see what they look like. I'm pretty sure different for `new Foo();`

Comment: It's still not quite clear (at least to me) what the problem is. Could you show some code where object literals and made via constructor makes a difference?

Comment: Once the object is run through `JSON.stringify()` there is no way to tell what type of object it was, short of adding a `type` property.

Comment: It's not a direct answer to your question, but the best approach I've seen is adding a property to your various objects, such as 'isGizmo` and `isDoodad` and using that property to route the raw object back into its container-type.

Comment: @bmceldowney not so fast, not determining type here yet, just wish to know if variable was instantiated using new and is a full fledged object with methods et al

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher can you elaborate on that isGizmo approach a little more, not getting it fully, maybe write an answer?

Comment: Whoever has voted to close this needs to say why, it's a fine question

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Its a fine question now.  The original question was extremely vague.

Comment: By the way: This is known as the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Your real question is actually different from the detailed question you asked.  You asked "how do I solve my problem this particular way" instead of asking "how do I solve my problem?"

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher lol, the problem and blessing with 5 whys is that it could go on forever, why don't i just ask howto program application x, btw, i dont think the original question changed

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the comments, if someone monkeys around enough with the properties or prototype of your variables, they can break any attempt to figure this out, but this should be pretty reliable for your use case:

```
function wasConstructed(obj) {
    var c = obj.constructor;
    return !(c === Object || c === Array || 
             c === Number || c === String || 
             c === Boolean);
}
```

This will return `false` for:

- Objects created with array literals and object literals
- Objects created with `new Object()` or `new Array()`
- Primitive values

And `true` for pretty much everything else.

A few caveats:

- If an object is created using `var z = Object.create(x);` then `wasConstructed(z)` will produce the same value as `wasConstructed(x)`
- Manually overwriting a objects' `.constructor` property can break this implementation

Incidentally, you can use the following as a fairly reliable way of determining the name of the constructor that was used to create your objects. You could use this as a generic way of storing that information during serialization:

```js
// Returns the name of fn if fn is a function, or null otherwise
function getFuncName(fn) {
  var funcNameRegex = /^\s*function\s*([^(]*)\(/,
    results = funcNameRegex.exec(fn.toString());
  return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : null;
}

function getConstructorName(obj) {
  return getFuncName(obj.constructor);
}

var d = new Date();
var cName = getConstructorName(d); // returns "Date"

console.log(cName);
```

One potential pitfall here is that this will not correctly determine the name if the constructor is anonymous:

```js
// Returns the name of fn if fn is a function, or null otherwise
function getFuncName(fn) {
  var funcNameRegex = /^\s*function\s*([^(]*)\(/,
    results = funcNameRegex.exec(fn.toString());
  return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : null;
}

function getConstructorName(obj) {
  return getFuncName(obj.constructor);
}

var C = function() {};
var i = new C();
var cName = getConstructorName(i);

console.log(cName);
```

One more option is to use the `name` property on the constructor, and this partially avoids the above problem, but note that this will **not** work in IE at all as it does not support `Function#name`:

```js
var C = function() {};
var i = new C();
var cName = i.constructor.name;

console.log(cName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, made up example:

```
// I am going to use a Gizmo class to demonstrate my point
function Gizmo(prop1, prop2, prop3) {
  this.prop1 = prop1;
  this.prop2 = prop2;
  this.prop3 = prop3;

  // Now, this will flag what kind of object I have
  this.isGizmo = true;
}

// Make the object
var myGizmo = new Gizmo("The cat", "Thing 1", "Thing 2");

// Serialize the object
var gizmoJson = JSON.stringify(myGizmo);
console.log(gizmoJson);

// Now, go to rebuild the object:
var rawObject = JSON.parse(gizmoJson);

// Note that rawObject needs revived.
console.log("Checking if rawObject is a Gizmo: ");
console.log(rawObject instanceof Gizmo);

if (rawObject.isGizmo) {
  var myGizmo2 = new Gizmo(rawObject.prop1, rawObject.prop2, rawObject.prop3);

  console.log(myGizmo2);
  console.log("Checking if myGizmo2 is a Gizmo: ");
  console.log(myGizmo2 instanceof Gizmo);
}
```

Comment: ok, now i get the point, but lets say you are given a random gizmo, do you need to revive it or not? you don't know because either way isGizmo = true, so unfortunately this does not solve the problem

Comment: @psp - Check my updated answer ... `rawObject instanceof Gizmo` is false, meaning the object needs revived.

Comment: so you are saying, knowing the type and using instanceof you could determine if it was constructed using new, is that what you are getting? any caveats in using instanceof?

Comment: None that I know of, but that should be searched (or asked) as a different question.   I've never needed to use `instanceof` because I always knew were the objects came from and they'd be refreshed, if needed, at load time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem domain is difficult since Javascript's prototype inheritance and object model differs somewhat from more traditional OOP languages that were implicitly referred in the question. There may not be clear answer for this due to these facts and differing definitions of the underlying concepts. Another perspective should probably be taken on the original issue.

For others looking for the same problem, one solution as pointed out in comments, is to use knowledge of the type and use instanceof operator.

```
c instanceof C // true

cSerializedCopy instanceof C // false
```